# Is it possible to build an Axway Appcelerator Android app with Product Flavors?

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

From my `tiapp.xml` file:

```
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
  <sdk-version>7.0.1.GA</sdk-version>
  <id>com.example.app</id>
```

This will create and install an app with id `com.example.app`. But now I need to have installed, side-by-side a beta version. In theory I can change the id and do:

```
  <id>com.example.app.beta</id>
```

And rebuild.

But I'm wondering if there's some kind of config, like we have [with Gradle in Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html) so I can do:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
   }
productFlavors {
    beta {
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Diego, any luck trying to setup flavors in Titanium? I am also trying the same.

Comment: @Sanman no. Finally gave up, as don't want to write a hook to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this repo: https://github.com/yomybaby/dev.tiapp

It is an hook to change things in tiapp.xml

Also search for `hook` in the Appcelerator documentation to get more information about CLI-Hooks

Comment: Thanks for this link. Looked promising, but trying to install the NPM module, it fails. Looks like abandoned, but still thanks. It's a starting point